# Oracle 10g problem with trigger

Tags: triggers, oracle10g

this is my first attempt with Oracle I would like use foreign key.

First I create some table, with autoincrement ID:

```
create table kruzky_tab(
  kruzokid number primary key  not null,
  meno  varchar2(50) not null,
  pocet number not null
)

create sequence kruzky_tab_seq 
  start with 1 
  increment by 1 
  nomaxvalue; 

create trigger kruzky_tab_trigger
  before insert on kruzky_tab
  for each row
    begin
      select kruzky_tab_seq.nextval into :new.kruzokid from dual;
    end;
```

Then I create second table with foreign key on table above:

```
create table studenti_tab(
  studentid number primary key not null,
  meno varchar2(50) not null,
  priezvisko varchar2(50) not null,
  email varchar2(50) not null,
  kruzokid references kruzky_tab
)
```

I try create same autoincrement trigger for studentid:

```
create sequence stundenti_tab_seq
  start with 1
  increment by 1
  nomaxvalue

create trigger studenti_tab_trigger
  before insert on studenti_tab
  for each row
    begin
      select studenti_tab_seq.nextval into :new.studnetid from dual;
    end;
```

I get this error:

> ERROR at line 2: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.STUDNETID'

```
1. create trigger `studenti_tab_trigger`
2. before insert on `studenti_tab`
3. for each row
4. begin
```

Trigger has same logic as trigger in `kruzky_tab` table on the top.
What is bad? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to rule out all typos of the identifier names, it looks as if you have some wrong characters in your identifiers:

`create sequence stundenti_tab_seq` (a "n" too much)

`select studenti_tab_seq.nextval into :new.studnetid from dual;` (sequence name does not match, `new.studnetid`is wrong)